# QML scoping within StateMachine and State

Tags: qml, qt5.6, qstatemachine

I read the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html) about QML scoping.

By this doc the following is allowed (under Component Instance Hierarchy second example from the above doc):

My StateMachine (`BaseStateMachine.qml`):

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

DSM.StateMachine {
   property string someProperty

   running: true
}
```

My State (`BaseState.qml`):

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

DSM.State {
   onEntered: someProperty = "some value"
}
```

My Main (`main.qml`):

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

ApplicationWindow {

   // ...

   BaseStateMachine {

      initialState: state

      BaseState {
          id: state
      }
   }
}
```

But I get the following error:
`qrc:/qml/BaseState.qml:4: ReferenceError: someProperty is not defined`

Am I misunderstanding something? I also read the doc about the StateMachine in qml and didn't find any exception for scoping within the StateMachines and States.

**Update:**

If I add an id to `BaseStateMachine.qml` like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

DSM.StateMachine {
   id: _baseStateMachine

   property string someProperty

   running: true
}
```

then QtCreator becomes aware of the `someProperty` in `BaseState.qml`. Under "becomes aware of" I mean, that if I ctrl/command+click on the property in `BaseState.qml` it brings me to `BaseStateMachine.qml`. As soon as I remove the id from `BaseStateMachine.qml` the QtCreator can't find the `someProperty` anymore.

Comment: I think, as `State` does not inherit `QObject` or anything else that would provide reference to a parent, the usual way to resolve the scope does not work and you need to provide it with actual ids. If you give the `BaseStateMachine` an id, and reference this ID in the `State` it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @derM. I am doing something similar currently. The funny thing, that if you add an id to the state machine, someProperty actually becomes known for the IDE in the state...weird behaviour.

Comment: Weired indeed. Thanks for this interesting insight!

Answer (score 0):

The difference to the second example in the documentation that you are referring to, is that in the example the "inner" elements are instantiated inside the "outer" element's definition file.

The equivalent in your setup would be using the `BaseState` type inside  the `BaseStateMachine.qml` file.

I.e. this should work

```
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

DSM.StateMachine {
    property string someProperty

    running: true
    initialState: state

    BaseState {
         id: state
    }
}
```